# VBA: How to store like values in arrays from a 2 column list

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I ll get right to what I want to accomplish. I have a 2 column list, as such:

```
 time1    pid1
 time2    pid1
 time3    pid4
 time4    pid4
 time5    pid4
 time6    pid1
 time7    pid1
 ...      ...
```

I already have the above information stored in an array. **My question is, using VBA, how can I go through the array and create sub-arrays for every new set of values, like so:**

```
 array1 would contain 
     pid1, time1
     pid1, time2

 array2 would contain
     pid4, time3
     pid4, time4
     pid4, time5

 array3 would contain
     pid1, time6
     pid1, time7
```

and so on until end of list??

I need it setup this particular way because I need to find the min/max time out of every set of like values, so then I could just go through every array and find the min/max time for that array's time values.

Comment: so you're just starting a new array each time you find a `pid_` with a number different to the adjacent `pid_` ?

Comment: yes, that is correct. That new array will contain all the similar pid_ along with their respective times, until a new pid_ is encountered, which will create another new array for that pid_. In the end, there will be many arrays with same pids; however, times will always be unique.

Comment: so it's not necessary to group (for example) the two `pid1` sections together?

Comment: No, pid1 sections must be kept separate, in their own group, as each section of similar pids represents a unique event that happened. If all similar pid1 sections were to be grouped together, then the ability to distinguish the different events would be lost.

Comment: Are time and pid two different arrays?

Comment: Original array contains both pid and time. From here, pid and time would also be contained in same sub-array. They COULD be two different arrays, as long as I would be able to find min/max time for each particular like value set.

Comment: Thought I would clarify previous response: no, time and pid are NOT two different arrays.

Comment: Reporting back...I have come up with a solution to this issue.  Will post answer at another time.